# what datatype should i use to display date datatype in Jquery Datatable plugin?

Tags: jquery

I used Jquery Datatable grid i want to bind date datatype in one of my coulmn i also want to sort the records based on date coulmn.i passed as string datatype for date column instead of date datatype.

which datatype can i use to sort string format date(month/date/year)?
if i want to use date type what datatype can i pass for coulmn sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in DataTables is based on the detected type of the data column (you can add your own type detection functions, or override automatic detection using sType). With this specific type given to the column, DataTables will apply the required sorting function.

[Data tables type based column sorting](http://datatables.net/development/sorting#type_based)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for sorting records based on date in datatable plugin.We should pass "date" datatype as parameter in coulmn sorting.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Employee').dataTable({ "aaSorting": [[4, "asc"]], "bSort": true, "aoColumns": [{ "sType": "html" }, { "sType": "html" }, { "sType": "html" }, { "sType": "html" }, { "sType": "date" }, { "sType": "html"}]
        });
    });
</script>
```